# List<SelectListItem>() for html helper DropDownListFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, selectlistitem

I am trying to generate a list as follows-

```
@using SkyTracker.Models
@model SkyTracker.Models.Outlet
@{
    var outletTypeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.OutletTypes)
    {
        //Exception Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'
        var newType = new SelectListItem { Text = item.OutletTypeName, Value = item.OutletTypeId };
        outletTypeList.Add(newType);
    }
}



<form method="post" action="@(ViewBag.BaseUrl)OutletManagement/Create?id=@ViewBag.RaId">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OutletTypeId, new { @class="required"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutletTypeId, outletTypeList, new {required="required" })

</form>
```

But I'm gettting an exception in the foreach loop. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Value` property of `SelectListItem` is tyeof `string` so if `OutletTypeId` is typeof `int`, then use `Value = item.OutletTypeId.ToString()`.

However that code belongs in the controller, not the view, and ideally you should be using a view model that contains a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OutletTypeList`

```
public class OutletVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an outlet type")]
    public int? OutletTypeId { get; set; } // nullable to protect against under-posting attacks
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OutletTypeList { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and in the controller

```
OutletVM model = new OutletVM()
{
    OutletTypeList = yourCollection.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.OutletTypeId.ToString(),
        Text = x.OutletTypeName
    },
    .... // set other properties of the view model
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutletTypeId, Model.OutletTypeList, "Please select")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OutletTypeId)
```

Note also that you should remove `new {required="required" }` which is HTML5 client side validation only and add a `RequiredAttribute` to the property your binding to so that you get both client and server side validation.

Consider also using

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "OutletManagement", new { id = @ViewBag.RaId }))
```

to generate the form element